# Arrayformula IF and ""AND"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

=ARRAYFORMULA({"BONUS";IF(and($H5:$H="SILVER";$J5:$J<$N5:$N);$F5:$F*20%;IF(and($H5:$H="GOLD";$J5:$J<$N5:$N);$F5:$F*10%;IF(and($H5:$H="PLATINUM";$J5:$J<$N5:$N);$F5:$F*5%;$J5:$J)))})

Please help, is there something wrong with my formula?
because the multiplication value cannot be calculated

I want to get the correct formula
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3z42.png)

Comment: `$F5:$F*20%` in place of `$F5:$F20%`. there's also `$F5:$F10%`

Comment: you have en error on multiplication.

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"BONUS";IF(AND($H5:$H="SILVER",$J5:$J<$N5:$N),$F5:$F*20%,IF(AND($H5:$H="GOLD",$J5:$J<$N5:$N),$F5:$F*10%,IF(AND($H5:$H="PLATINUM",$J5:$J<$N5:$N),$F5:$F*5%, $J5:$J)),)})
`

Comment: I have used this formula but it doesn't work for the calculations.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` instead of `AND`.

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"BONUS";IF(($H5:$H="SILVER")*($J5:$J<$N5:$N);$F5:$F*20%;IF(($H5:$H="GOLD")*($J5:$J<$N5:$N);$F5:$F*10%;IF(($H5:$H="PLATINUM")*($J5:$J<$N5:$N);$F5:$F*5%;$J5:$J)),)})`